# Apache JMeter exception NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, jmeter, apache-commons-io

I'm trying to run load testing on some transactions recorded with JMeter however when executing it shows the error below

> Exception in thread "HomePage_thread 10-2"
> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'void
> org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.closeQuietly(java.io.Closeable,
> java.util.function.Consumer)'     at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.readResponse(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1982)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPAbstractImpl.readResponse(HTTPAbstractImpl.java:476)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:673)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1296)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1285)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
> at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)

Any idea what can be the problem?

Comment: Are you running distributed environment? what's jmeter version and its plugins? what's your commons-io jar version ?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ and deeplearning4j, specifically rl4j... jmeter version is 5.4.1, and maven plugins and dependencies

Comment: check for commons-io jar(s)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Classic [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell)

1. Deeplearning4j [depends on commons-io 2.5](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j-core/1.0.0-beta7)
2. JMeter HTTP compone [depends on commons-io 2.8](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.jmeter/ApacheJMeter_http/5.4.1)

You need to amend your project classpath in order to include only commons-io 2.8 in order to get JMeter working or downgrade to [JMeter 3.1](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/whats-new-jmeter-31/) which relies on commons-io 2.5

Comment: I just downgraded my JMeter version to 3.1 and now the transactions are executing normally without errors. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

Your settings requires at least [commons-io-2.7.jar](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#closeQuietly-java.io.Closeable-java.util.function.Consumer-) to be available

> public static void closeQuietly(Closeable closeable,
> Consumer consumer)

> **Since:** 2.7

Delete old versions of this jar if exists

Comment: I checked to be sure, and Yes I have included commons-io-2.8.0.jar to the External Libraries of my project...

Comment: @ErblinIsaku remove old versions of this jar

Answer (score 0):

I had to face this same issue when trying to run my first Jmeter test plan.

- Jmeter version I use - v5.4.3
- commons.io jar version I had - 2.6 & 2.8

What I have done is simply delete both commons.io jar files (above mentioned) from the (->lib). Then I downloaded the latest commons.io jar version (2.11) to the above path.
Now I was able to run the test plan without getting this issue.